# Is there a way to monitor syslog in realtime from a C++ application under Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, syslog

I'm on an ARM Linux board that has some USB issues when a USB 1.1 device is connected or disconnected to the USB 3.0 ports, in that case a kernel message is generated, something like:

> [14720.301195@0] usb 1-1.4: urb status -32

This message literally floods the syslog repeating itself hundreds of times. My application needs to intercept this message as soon as possible and perform some actions such as release some peripherals and re-instantiate some objects. Since the error is generated only while other USB 1.1 devices are open and in use, as soon as I release them the error disappears. This seems the only way to prevent the message flood.

I've tried with polling on the bash command:

> tail -n 1 /var/log/syslog

but apparently the log file isn't updated quickly enough, even if I mount /var/log/ in a ram disk (ramfs).

I don't know how else I could "connect" to the syslog and read the messages in real-time, as soon as they are generated.

Comment: If your kernel is 3.5.0 or newer, there is https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/dev-kmsg which is used by `dmesg -w` ... Assuming that is a kernel message. It does look like one.

Comment: Kernel version is 4.9.277-76. Thanks for the link, I'll give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `-f` (follow) flag.

> tail -f /var/log/syslog

Then you don't need to poll it every time. The following seems to work on my Linux:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen("tail -f /var/log/syslog", "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe)
        throw runtime_error("popen failed");

    array<char, 4096> buffer;
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()))
        cout << "SYSLOG: " << buffer.data() << endl;
}
```

and can be debugged with:

```sh
python -c 'import syslog; syslog.syslog("Hello syslog")'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me because, as I said in my post, the file /var/log/syslog isn't updated quickly enough to catch the error in time and take action. I get the updates only after the error flood is terminated, but I can see it going on the serial console.

Comment: Saving logs is normally not time critical, hence `rsyslog` and other often aggregate logs before saving them. `dmesg -w` (as mentioned by @dratenik) should give more "real-time" results, but needs sudo AFAIK. Maybe you can communicate with the USB driver directly for a more proper solution.